# Is it possible to update a table using WHERE email = $_SESSION['email']

Tags: php, sql

I want to update an already existing table it only has email and I want to add first name and last name does this code work to do so?

```
     UPDATE table
     SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname'
      WHERE email= '$_SESSION['email'].';
```

Or can I also use this

```
     $sql="INSERT INTO            $tbl_name(fname, lname)VALUES( '$fname, $lname')"  WHERE email= '$_SESSION['email'].';
```

Comment: If you want to update, you need to use UPDATE, as in the first example. INSERT will multiply insertes. Anyway, first UPDATE has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` has a syntax error (problem with apostrophes.)
`INSERT` will not update but multiply rows. That is `not` what you want to have.
Here is my suggested query:

```
$sql="UPDATE table SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname' WHERE email='".$_SESSION["email"]."'" ;
```

Comment: @DanFromGermany It is by no means *deprecated* and I see neither up nor downvotes on this answer. Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double#example-79 (specifically, the `koolaid1` example)

Comment: @Phil why you downvote my answer? Good: `'" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'` Bad: `'$_SESSION[email]'` see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Answer (score 0):

Fix your quotes, like so:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(email) VALUES ( '" . $email . "') WHERE email = '" .  $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:** In case of simple Update Query

```
$user_email = $_SESSION['email'];

$fname      = 'Thierry';
$lname      = 'Henry';


UPDATE table
     SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname'
      WHERE email= '$user_email';
```

Insertion is not a good idea here. It might duplicate your records.

**If you want to be more specific than Go like this: Just providing your general syntax. No real time Syntax:**

```
    $user_email = $_SESSION['email'];

    $fname      = 'Thierry';
    $lname      = 'Henry';

$check_user = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = "user_email"';

if($check_user)
{
  YOUR UPDATE QUERY
}
else
{
 YOUR INSERT QUERY
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using `mysql_` functions you should also escape the input:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']);
```

**Disclaimer** for idiots: This does not imply I suggest to use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

You should also check against `NULL` and empty values in your query.

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO " . $table . "
        SET email='" . $email . "'
        WHERE email='" .  $email . "'
          AND email IS NOT NULL
          AND email != ''";
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Please don't downvote if this doesn't exactly fit, just use `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with the same syntax then.

Comment: Please don't recommend the deprecated MySQL extension.

Comment: I didn't recommend it. Read the answer again before downvoting.